# gmap loaded after document ready

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-api

i use this function for generate my gmap when the user click on button

```
function getGMap(id_map,lat,lng) {

        var mapOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
          zoom: 14,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(id_map),
            mapOptions);

        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map:map,
            //animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
            icon: "../imgmdg/icons/map_pin.png"
        });
}



$(".toggleMap").click(function(){

       var id_map=$(this).attr('data-idmap');
       var lat=$(this).attr('data-lat');
       var lng=$(this).attr('data-lng');
       var status=$(this).attr('data-status');

       if(status=="0") { 

           console.log(id_map);
           console.log(lat);
           console.log(lng);
           $("#"+id_map).html('');
           getGMap(id_map,lat,lng); 


           $(this).attr('data-status','1');

       }

});
```

trigger: (class toggleMap in the second 'li')

```
 <ul class="nav nav-tabs tabsFixBorder">
      <li class="active"><a href="#<?=$menu->id()?>tab1" data-toggle="tab" class="tab1">Men&ugrave;</a></li>
      <li><a href="#<?=$menu->id()?>tab2" data-toggle="tab" class="tab2 toggleMap" data-idmap="map_<?=$menu->id()?>" data-lat="<?=$restaurant->lat()?>" data-lng="<?=$restaurant->lng()?>" data-status="0">Profilo</a></li>
    </ul>
```

and in my page there are some div like this:

```
<div id="map_1" class="gmap_container"></div>
<div id="map_2" class="gmap_container"></div>
<div id="map_3" class="gmap_container"></div>
```

this is my css:

```
html{
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Verdana; 
    font-size: 12px; 
    color: #2d2929;    
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    background-image: url('../imgmdg/pattern/pattern.jpg'); 
}
.gmap_container{
    display: block;
    /*tried with height:100% as well*/
    height:200px;
    width:100%;
    background-color: #fff !important;
    margin: 0px;
    padding-bottom:10px;
}
```

it work only for the first click I do
after one click the map have some problem
(it load only a part of the map)
this is the screenshot of the problem: http://postimg.org/image/7apl01wn7/

thanks all in advice

Comment: and how is the function called, what's the relation between the divs and the function?  Show us your click event handler code please.

Comment: i've edited and added what you ask :)
thank you duncan

Comment: Possible problems: The data-idmap attribute starts `map_` but your HTML says `gmap_`.  You're using lat and lng values read from your HTML; you should probably use parseFloat() to make sure they are correctly converted to numerics, not strings.

Comment: i tryed to add parseFloat before calling getGMap(): 
getGMap(id_map,parseFloat(lat),parseFloat(lng));
didn't work.. it make the same problem
(the first click on trigger still work)

Comment: what CSS do you have for the divs you're placing the map into? See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#HTML5

Comment: I've added the css part, i tried height:100% for the div cointainer, but still not works

Comment: I don't see anything using the .gmap_container class

Comment: oh! really sorry I forgot to fix the post in my last edit

Comment: thank you duncan, i found the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i have found the solution for my problem:
at the end i've used the bootstrap tab as a container for my map.
the trick is load the map after the tab is loaded (for example i used the bootstrap event 'shown')

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown', function (e) {
    getGMap(id_map,lat,lng);
});
```

hope this help